# How to create a Django Rest API that can accept and return a file without a model

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I want to create an API view without a model that accepts an excel file, allows me to manipulate the file, then returns the manipulated file back. The reason I don't want to use a model is because I don't want the excel file saved.

serializers.py

```
class ExcelSheetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    excel_file = serializers.FileField()
```

views.py

```
class ExcelSheetView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ExcelSheetSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        print(request)
        serializer = ExcelSheetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer)
            print(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Doing `print(serializer)` gives `ExcelSheetSerializer(data=<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['hVPkI5U9pfxZjzRer3mRWJXglbeiLIvFvnNBsB88V4x4wKu4Q1MiY3EQI1kqRaxQ'], 'excel_file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: EUR Nov 2021 Form.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>): excel_file = FileField()`

but trying to access `serializer.data` gives `{'excel_file': None}`.

I tried using a parser `parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]`, but that made it so I couldn't upload a file.

[image]

Comment: you have implemented a POST method and you are sending a GET request (in screen shot). why is that?

Comment: @umair Oh im not trying to send a get request, that just automatically pops up when I go to localhost:8000/api, the part about me not being able to send a file with the `parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]` refers to the Media Type and Content fields which previously was just an upload file button where I could upload a file

Comment: @KJ so youre saying I need to use a model if I want to upload a file? What if I don't want the file to be saved to a database?